# Displaying conditional content from MondoDB to a list element, according to an option value selected by a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to conditionally display documents from MongoDB on a webpage. The user should select an option from a select element and that will filter the documents accordingly. If the user selects the first-year option, only items with the database field of "first-year" should be displayed on the page using the ejs template like on the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7h47.png)

I managed to pull all the documents from the database and was able to display them all on the ejs template. I also managed to add an event listener on the select option to render conditional information on the template. I am just not sure how to connect the data documents to the select element.

This is my registration.ejs file

```
        <label for="year">Select year</label>
        <select name="year" id="year">
          <option value="0">Year 1</option>
          <option value="1">Year 2</option>
          <option value="2">Year 3</option>
          <option value="3">Year 4</option>
        </select>

        <div class="modules">
          <% for (const module of modules) {%>
            <ul id="module-list">
              <li>
                <!-- <input type="checkbox" name="module" id="<%= module._id %>" value="<%= module._id%>"/>
                <label for="<%= module._id%>"><%= module.moduleCode%></label> -->
              </li>
            </ul>        
          <% } %>
      </div>
```

This is my browser-side script

```
const yearSelectorElement = document.getElementById('year');

async function updateModules() {
  if (yearSelectorElement.value == "0") {  
    document.getElementById('module-list').innerHTML = "<li>Item1</li>"
  } else if (yearSelectorElement.value == "1") {
    document.getElementById('module-list').innerHTML = "<li>Item2</li>"
  } else if (yearSelectorElement.value == "2") {
    document.getElementById('module-list').innerHTML = "<li>Item3</li>"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('module-list').innerHTML = "<li>Item4</li>"
  }
}

yearSelectorElement.addEventListener('change', updateModules);
```

This is my registration controller file

```
const db = require('../data/database');

async function getRegistration (req, res) {
  const modules = await db.getDb().collection('modules').find().toArray();
  
  res.render('student/registration/registration', { modules: modules });
 
};

module.exports = {
  getRegistration: getRegistration,
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out on my own. I rendered the data from MongoDB to my EJS template. I then filtered the data using several divs with a class of hidden and then used the select element to add or remove the class on the div to show or hide the content.

This is my registration EJS file now

```html
<select id="yearSelector">
  <option value="">Select a year</option>
  <option value="year1">Year 1</option>
  <option value="year2">Year 2</option>
  <option value="year3">Year 3</option>
  <option value="year4">Year 4</option>    
</select>

<div id="year1" class="hidden">
  <ul>
    <% for (const module of modules) { %>
      <% if (module.year === 1) { %>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="<%= module.moduleCode%>" value="<%= module.moduleCode%>"> 
          <label for="<%= module.moduleCode%>"><%= module.moduleCode%></label>
        </li>
      <% } %>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="year2" class="hidden">
  <ul>
    <% for (const module of modules) { %>
      <% if (module.year === 2) { %>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="<%= module.moduleCode%>" value="<%= module.moduleCode%>"> 
          <label for="<%= module.moduleCode%>"><%= module.moduleCode%></label>
        </li>
      <% } %>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="year3" class="hidden">
  <ul>
    <% for (const module of modules) { %>
      <% if (module.year === 3) { %>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="<%= module.moduleCode%>" value="<%= module.moduleCode%>"> 
          <label for="<%= module.moduleCode%>"><%= module.moduleCode%></label>
        </li>
      <% } %>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="year4" class="hidden">
  <ul>
    <% for (const module of modules) { %>
      <% if (module.year === 4) { %>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="<%= module.moduleCode%>" value="<%= module.moduleCode%>"> 
          <label for="<%= module.moduleCode%>"><%= module.moduleCode%></label>
        </li>
      <% } %>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Browser-side script:

```js
const yearSelector = document.getElementById("yearSelector");
const year1Element = document.getElementById("year1");
const year2Element = document.getElementById("year2");
const year3Element = document.getElementById("year3");
const year4Element = document.getElementById("year4");

yearSelector.addEventListener("change", ()=> {
  if (yearSelector.value === "year1") {
    year1Element.classList.remove("hidden");
    year2Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year3Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year4Element.classList.add("hidden");
  } else if (yearSelector.value === "year2") {
    year1Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year2Element.classList.remove("hidden");
    year3Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year4Element.classList.add("hidden");
  } else if (yearSelector.value === "year3") {
    year1Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year2Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year3Element.classList.remove("hidden");
    year4Element.classList.add("hidden");
  } else if (yearSelector.value === "year4") {
    year1Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year2Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year3Element.classList.add("hidden");
    year4Element.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
});
```